# How to group-by and plot for each hour of each day of week

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I need help figuring out how to plot sub-plots for easy comparison from my dataframe shown:

```
  Date                   A        B         C              
2017-03-22 15:00:00     obj1    value_a    other_1
2017-03-22 14:00:00     obj2    value_ns   other_5
2017-03-21 15:00:00     obj3    value_kdsa other_23
2014-05-08 17:00:00     obj2    value_as   other_4
2010-07-01 20:00:00     obj1    value_as   other_0
```

I am trying to graph the occurrences of each hour for each respective day of the week. So count the number of occurrences for each day of the week and hour and plot them on subplots like the ones shown below.

[image]

If this question sounds confusing please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: `counts` are just the number of rows for each hour of each day? Or is there any consideration of the other columns?

Comment: Yes. So for example for the 'Thursday' subplot I would like all of the rows with a date that occurs on a Thursday. The counts will then be the number of rows that occur for each time on a Thursday.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this with multiple `groupby`. Since we know there are 7 days in a week, we can specify that number of panels. If you `groupby(df.Date.dt.dayofweek)`, you can use the group index as the index for your subplot axes:

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10000
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='1.09min', periods=n),
                   'A': np.random.randint(1,10,n),
                   'B': np.random.normal(0,1,n)})
```

#### Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=7, figsize=(30,5))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)  #Remove some whitespace between subplots

for idx, gp in df.groupby(df.Date.dt.dayofweek):
    ax[idx].set_title(gp.Date.dt.day_name().iloc[0])  #Set title to the weekday

    (gp.groupby(gp.Date.dt.hour).size().rename_axis('Tweet Hour').to_frame('')
        .reindex(np.arange(0,24,1)).fillna(0)
        .plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[idx], rot=0, ec='k', legend=False))

    # Ticks and labels on leftmost only
    if idx == 0:
        _ = ax[idx].set_ylabel('Counts', fontsize=11)

    _ = ax[idx].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=7,
                            labelleft=(idx == 0), left=(idx == 0))

# Consistent bounds between subplots. 
lb, ub = list(zip(*[axis.get_ylim() for axis in ax]))
for axis in ax:
    axis.set_ylim(min(lb), max(ub)) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you'd like to make the aspect ratio less extreme, then consider plotting a 4x2 grid. It's a very similar plot as above, once we `flatten` the axis array. There's some integer and remainder division to figure out which `axes` need the labels.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, figsize=(20,10))
fig.delaxes(ax[1,3])  #7 days in a week, remove 8th panel
ax = ax.flatten()  #Far easier to work with a flattened array

lsize=8
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.15)  #Remove some whitespace between subplots

for idx, gp in df.groupby(df.Date.dt.dayofweek):
    ax[idx].set_title(gp.Date.dt.day_name().iloc[0])  #Set title to the weekday

    (gp.groupby(gp.Date.dt.hour).size().rename_axis([None]).to_frame()
        .reindex(np.arange(0,24,1)).fillna(0)
        .plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[idx], rot=0, ec='k', legend=False))

    # Titles on correct panels
    if idx%4 == 0:
        _ = ax[idx].set_ylabel('Counts', fontsize=11)
    if (idx//4 == 1) | (idx%4 == 3):
        _ = ax[idx].set_xlabel('Tweet Hour', fontsize=11) 

    # Ticks on correct panels
    _ = ax[idx].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=lsize,
                            labelbottom=(idx//4 == 1) | (idx%4 == 3), 
                            bottom=(idx//4 == 1) | (idx%4 == 3),
                            labelleft=(idx%4 == 0), 
                            left=(idx%4 == 0))

# Consistent bounds between subplots. 
lb, ub = list(zip(*[axis.get_ylim() for axis in ax]))
for axis in ax:
    axis.set_ylim(min(lb), max(ub)) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to make the graphs any bigger while still the same ratio?  Even if i need to scroll to see some

Comment: @momojoh1 you can play around with the `figsize` tuple on the first line to adjust the aspect ratio and overall size. This is a rather extreme aspect ratio, so perhaps you can consider plotting two rows, though that will mess up the simple `ax[idx]` indexing I used above. (i.e. something like `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, figsize=(20,10)`)

Comment: @momojoh1 let me know if that looks better.

Answer (score 4):

What about using `seaborn`? `sns.FacetGrid` was made for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# make some data
date = pd.date_range('today', periods=100, freq='2.5H')

# put in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : date
})

# create day_of_week and hour columns
df['dow'] = df.date.dt.day_name()
df['hour'] = df.date.dt.hour

# create facet grid
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df.groupby([
    'dow',
    'hour'
]).hour.count().to_frame(name='day_hour_count').reset_index(), col='dow', col_order=[
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
], col_wrap=3)

# map barplot to each subplot
g.map(sns.barplot, 'hour', 'day_hour_count');
```

[image: barplots]

Comment: I am getting this warning:  `remove_na is deprecated and is a private function. Do not use.`

Comment: What version of `seaborn` are you using? This is with version 9.0